# SQL Cycles or Multiple Cascade Paths

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having a problem with cycles. I am developing inventory system for IT department. 
I am having problem with 3 tables.

`INVENTORY` table that is used to keep history of user actions and `SOFTWARE` and `HARDWARE` tables are used for storing inventory.

I would like to keep a single `inventoryID` that is unique for `SOFTWARE` and `HARDWARE` tables and when I use `ON CASCADE DELETE` I get an error:

> Msg 1785, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
>   Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'fk_inventory_inventoryIDhw' on table 'inventory' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

Here are my tables. Could anyone help me out? How can fix the issue. Can't find right solution on the web. Thanks

```
CREATE TABLE inventory
( 
   statusID int,
   inventoryStatus nvarchar(15),
   inventoryID int,
   userName nvarchar(15),
   dates datetime2,
   inventoryAction nvarchar(10),
   categoryID int,

   CONSTRAINT pk_inventory_statusID PRIMARY KEY(statusID),
   CONSTRAINT fk_inventory_inventoryIDsw FOREIGN KEY(inventoryID) REFERENCES     software(inventoryID) ON DELETE CASCADE, 
   CONSTRAINT fk_inventory_inventoryIDhw FOREIGN KEY(inventoryID) REFERENCES hardware(inventoryID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
   CONSTRAINT fk_inventory_userName FOREIGN KEY(userName) REFERENCES users(userName) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
GO

CREATE TABLE hardware
(
   inventoryID int,
   hardwareID int,
   partNumber nvarchar(15),
   serial nvarchar(50),
   price float,
   supportID int,
   manufacturerID int,
   categoryID int,
   description nvarchar,
   deviceTypeID int,

   CONSTRAINT pk_hardware_inventoryID PRIMARY KEY(inventoryID),
   CONSTRAINT fk_hardware_categoryID FOREIGN KEY(categoryID) REFERENCES category(categoryID) ON DELETE CASCADE, 
   CONSTRAINT fk_hardware_supportID FOREIGN KEY(supportID) REFERENCES support(supportID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
   CONSTRAINT fk_hardware_deviceTypeID FOREIGN KEY(deviceTypeID) REFERENCES deviceType(deviceTypeID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
   CONSTRAINT fk_hardware_manufacturerID FOREIGN KEY(manufacturerID) REFERENCES manufacturer(manufacturerID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
)
GO

CREATE TABLE software
(
   inventoryID int,
   softwareID int,
   version nvarchar(10),
   name nvarchar(50),
   license nvarchar(50),
   price float,
   supportID int,
   categoryID int,
   manufacturerID int,
   programTypeID int,
   description nvarchar,

   CONSTRAINT pk_software_inventoryID PRIMARY KEY(inventoryID),
   CONSTRAINT fk_software_categoryID FOREIGN KEY(categoryID) REFERENCES category(categoryID) ON DELETE CASCADE, 
   CONSTRAINT fk_software_supportID FOREIGN KEY(supportID) REFERENCES support(supportID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
   CONSTRAINT fk_software_programTypeID FOREIGN KEY(programTypeID) REFERENCES     programType(programTypeID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
   CONSTRAINT fk_software_manufacturerID FOREIGN KEY(manufacturerID) REFERENCES     manufacturer(manufacturerID) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
GO
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` columns (e.g. `description`), variables and parameters that you use

Comment: Your foreign key relationships are all wrong - they should go from `Software` and `Hardware` to `Inventory` - but not also the other way around! You need to have an `InventoryId (FK)` in both `Software` and `Hardware` - but you most definitely don't need FK constraints to those "child" tables in `Inventory`! That's what's causing the cycles in your `ON DELETE CASCADE` setup!

Comment: @marc_s thanks for comment. I will add length to nvarchar. Regarding the PK and FK. Instead of having inventory PK in Software and Hardware tables I need to set them as FK and in the inventory table it should be PK? I am a bit confused.

Comment: Yes - you have the `Inventory` which defines the `InventoryID` as the PK - and then you have two child tables for soft- and hardware which both act as "child" tables (a bit like an object inheritance in OOP) and they just need to reference the `Inventory.InventoryID` - that's all, there's no need for a FK from the inventory to the child tables, too - that would be too much....

Comment: @marc_S Thank you for the help. It seems like working now. Since now there is a normal tree I don't have the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can remember multiple fk constraints on the same column associated with more than one parent table is not workable.  You might need another table to maintain this relationship.  Please see: http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=173589

Answer (score 0):

Having the same column as part of multipe Foriegn Key Constraints associated with multiple parent tables create referential integrity issues.

The best approach would be to normalise the design and introduce an intermediate table to retain the relation as 2 (or more) relations.